# ejabberd Integration on iOS Using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework

I have little knowledge about ejabberd. I hope someone can help me by providing step by step guide to use with iOS application.

Installed by downloading ejabberd installer for OS X.

Now I need to start with application from scratch:

1. Need to create a new table for providing real time posting and tagging feature.
2. Wants to know how can I view the default ejabberd database via Sqlite or any DBMS tool.
3. How can I insert and retrieve information from ejabberd in my iOS application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Connecting to ejabberd is not different than connecting to any other XMPP server.
There is a very nice step by step tutorial for XMPP framework that should help you get started: https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios